# webkit-touch-callout by default not working

Tags: xcode, cordova

I'm building a small iPhone App and by default (apparently) the webkit-touch-callout function that allows a contextual menu when a user taps & holds an element (an image for example). In the case of an image, when you tap-hold it, it'll prompt you to either save or copy the image.

I see all sorts of tips on how to disable this - by default, it should be enabled. However this is not true in my case and I'm trying desperately to ENABLE this.

My HTML is fairly straightforward:

`<img src="files/image.jpg" id="theimage" style="margin:30px auto;display:block;width:90%;height:auto;" />`

And in my CSS, I have:

`* {
   -webkit-user-select: auto!important;
   -webkit-touch-callout: auto!important;
}`

However when I tap-hold an image in my app, nothing happens. When I open Safari in the xCode emulator however and I browse to a Google images image, it works perfectly.

Any help/ideas please?

Comment: to be specific, THIS is the kind of contextual menu I'm looking to achieve: http://d.pr/kAdI